# Rails 5: How to declare HEAD 200 in Rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, savon

I have a webhook sent to a page on my app, and I am catching SOAP errors from processing the data, but I want to send to the webhook a 200 status. Is this possible in the controller?

## controller

```
def example_method

  ...

rescue Savon::SOAPFault => error

  ...
  
  # Respond to the HTTP POST request by giving the 'all clear'
  head 200

  raise

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off don't place soap calls directly into your controller - instead create a client class or [service object](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services) that handles it.

Your controller should only really know that it calls some kind of service and that it may fail or succeed - if you are catching library specific errors in your controller you are on your way down the rabbit hole.

### So how do you rescue exceptions in your controller?

You can rescue them inline:

```
class SomethingController

  def do_something

    begin
      # Something.this_may_blow_up!
    rescue SomeError => error
      head :ok and return
    end
  end
end
```

The key here is `and return` which halts the controller flow and prevents double render errors.

The other method is by using [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html).

```
class ThingsController

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
    render :not_found and return
  end

  def show
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

The above is an example of how you can create a custom 404 page per controller. What happens is that when the action on the controller is invoked it is wrapped in a `begin..rescue` block that looks for `rescue_from` handlers in the controller.

Comment: What a really helpful answer! Looks like I need to go back to the drawing board. In the "Using Services to Keep Your Rails Controllers Clean and DRY" page you linked, he uses `rescue` on it's own... Is that to say `rescue` on it's own without arguments can act as a 'catch all'?

Comment: Yes, if you use `rescue` without an exception type it will catch all exceptions - its called Pokémon exception handling and is a really bad practice...

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain further or link to why Pokémon exception handling is bad practice? In my mind a 'catch all' sounds a safe idea

Comment: Its not - it swallows errors like `NoMethodError` or `ArgumentError` which mask bugs in the program. Its really just sweeping problems under the carpet. http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/why-rescue-nil-is-bad

Comment: There are some very limited cases when building frameworks where you using a catch-all is necessary for example for logging and displaying error pages. But not in application code. http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/319088/is-indiscriminately-catching-exceptions-pokemon-exception-handling-ever-accept